LLC halfbridge design startup fault
I have an LLC halfbridge design, using TI's UCC256404 chip, and I'm having a fault declared during initial startup.  My primary side aux rail gets bumped up beyond the regulation point, which causes the chip to declare a fault, and enter a 1s hiccup time.  It will usually catch on the restart, and startup ok.  Here are a couple plots showing what I'm seeing (Green is my primary aux rail of ~15V; Purple is primary side current; Blue is the switching node between the two primary FETs; yellow is my 75V output rail) -


You can see that preceding this fault being declared, the switching timing of the gates' changes.  This seems to be a part of the chip's softstart (I assume), but I'm not sure why my aux rail gets bumped up like that.  The bumps on the rail are only for part of the top FET's on time, which maybe means there is stored energy in the transformer that has to go somewhere?
Snip of my schematic -

My design uses the xfrm's leakage of 85uH as the resonant inductor, and the primary side is 595uH.  The input to the LLC is a 450VDC rail generated from a PFC boost converter (which looks like is working just fine).  I'm not sure if this suggests some sort of grounding issue on the board or maybe I need ceramic cap on the my primary aux rail, or something else entirely.  Any thoughts would be appreciated.
Edit 1:
VCR voltage in yellow:


That looks normal to me.
I don't have specific transformer construction info, just the spec sheet -

Edit 2:
ISNS signal plots -

I can certainly try a lower Risns value, but would that affect the blips on my aux rail?  It will potentially lower the signal at which a fault is declared, but I think those blips are still problematic.  What should be a 15V hits about ~25V for a short time.

Where is the aux winding in relation to the primary? Do you have a transformer winding diagram? Can you show VCR node as well?

Added some info above showing VCR and what I have for the transformer.

This could be because of a "higher than required" ISNS resistor, especially when starting into a large capacitive load (I don't know if this is the case in your application). Try with a smaller R34 (e.g. 120R) and see if it helps.

What does the ISNS signal look like at the IC, with proper pigtail probing?

I added a couple plots of ISNS.  The output of the LLC drives a boost converter that takes the 75V generated from the LLC, and puts a constant current into an LED load.  But at this point during the LLC's startup, the boost converter isn't doing anything.  The load is really just the (3) 150uF alum caps on the secondary of the transformer.

Do you have an inductance meter, or an equivalent method (e.g. scope, function generator, resistor and capacitor e.g. this method on my site)? Can measure L_aux with pri or sec shorted, and see which one is lower (more closely coupled).

I tried a lower R.isns with no real success.  I went from 200 ohms to 140 ohms.  Everything pretty much looks the same.  I do have an inductance meter, but I would have to take the transformer off the board to measure it - I just have a couple samples from the manufacturer.  Not that I can't do that, but it's a little cumbersome, that's all.

1) What's the switching frequency, especially in the last oscillogram? I see a few hundred Hertz judging from the 5.0ms/div on the bottom right and it is too low. 2) The primary/tank current (both the waveform and the amplitudes) looks weird to me. 3) The ISNS voltage already exceeds the IC's OCP trigger thresholds. 4) You might have a response-related issue because you're using an unregulated winding for regulation. Try reducing R67 (e.g. 4k7).


The 5ms/div is for the zoomed out plot (the narrow ribbon at the top of the pic).  The larger part of the picture is at 5us/div.  Before the weirdness happens, I'm switching at about 175kHz.  That then jumps down to 117kHz for the last 5 cycles.  2) I believe the SS function of the chip makes the initial waveform look weird.  Once it drops to 117kHz Fsw, the waveform looks a little more normal, but I agree that the amplitude is way high.  3) I realized that, too, but not sure why.  4) I will try that when I'm back in the office on Tuesday.  Thanks.


So I tried lowering R67 with no effect.  I think that makes sense.  At this point in the start up, I'm nowhere close to being at my regulation point of 75V (Vout is only around 40V at this point during startup), so there's no current flowing through the opto.  The bumps on my Vaux rail seem like they might line up with the time that the high side FET is freewheeling before the primary current changes direction.  Does that make sense?  And if so, does that point to a particular issue, or at least a point to further investigate?
